# How to merge multiple json in python

Tags: python, json, merge

I have a list which holds multiple json strings like this

```
a = [{"name": "Alex"},{"Age": 25},{"Address": "16, Mount View"}]
```

I would like to merge these into a single array like this

```
a = [{"name": "Alex","Age": 25,"Address": "16, Mount View"}]
```

I have tried using `jsonmerge` but no luck its working fine when using `head' and`base` values.

Can some one give me a hand in this.

I have also gone through a similar question in stack but it shows merge for separate json but not json in a list [How to merge two json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698556/5039470)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Comment: This has nothing to to with JSON, since at this point you simply have a list of Python dictionary objects. There are already many answers on how to merge a list of dicts together, e.g. [the answers to this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict).

Answer (score 3):

First, these are python dicts

```
[{"name": "Alex"},{"Age": 25},{"Address": "16, Mount View"}]
```

you may call json.dumps on them and turn them into "json strings".

2nd, you can use the dict update method

```
a =  [{"name": "Alex"},{"Age": 25},{"Address": "16, Mount View"}]
d = {}
for small_dict in a:
    d.update(small_dict)
print(d) # Yay!
a = [d]
```

Be warned! , if you have duplicate keys they will override each other

Also take a look on "ChainMap"

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap

Comment: Is there a way not to replace the duplicate keys?

Comment: using the reversed list will give you that - a[::-1] (its just replacing from the end to start :) )

Comment: how do i use the reversed list, should i use it as `for small_dict in -a:`

Comment: @TonyRoczz - for small_dict in a[::-1]:

Answer (score 2):

To add to the @yoav glazner's answer and if you are on Python 3.3+, you can use [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> a = [{"name": "Alex"},{"Age": 25},{"Address": "16, Mount View"}]
>>> dict(ChainMap(*a))
{'name': 'Alex', 'Age': 25, 'Address': '16, Mount View'}
```

See more about the `ChainMap` use cases here:

- [What is the purpose of collections.ChainMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392976/what-is-the-purpose-of-collections-chainmap)