# Going through a List of keys to get to a value

Tags: python, json

I have a program that will loop through a set of nested dictionaries and lists to get to a value. Along the way, I try to store the index or key in a List.

In another file, I want to use those list of Keys to get to a value in the same location and copy it over.

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I'll provide my current code though.

```
import json

# o_name = input("What is the json file name to transfer info from?")
o_name = "fu"
o_file = open(o_name + ".json", "r")
o_json = json.load(o_file)

# t_name = input("What is the json file name to copy the info to?")
t_name = "bar"
t_file = open(t_name + ".json", "r")
t_json = json.load(t_file)

key_list = []

def nested_values_iterator(obj):
    global key_list

    # Iterate over all values of given dictionary
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for index, value in enumerate(obj):
            key_list.append(index)
            # If value is list then iterate over all its values
            for v in nested_values_iterator(value):
                yield v
        if len(key_list) > 0:
            print("popping list " + str(key_list.pop()))
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for value in obj:
            key_list.append(value)
            # If value is dict then iterate over all its values
            for v in nested_values_iterator(obj[value]):
                yield v
        if len(key_list) > 0:
            print("popping dictionary " + str(key_list.pop()))
    else:
        yield obj
        key_list.pop()


for data in nested_values_iterator(o_json):
    # Copy the info over
    print(key_list)
    print("data: " + str(data))
    entry = t_json
    for key in key_list[0:len(key_list)-1]:
        entry = entry[key]
        try:
            if type(entry) == dict:
                print("entry: " + str(entry[key_list[-1]]) + " = " + str(data))
                entry[key_list[-1]] = data
            elif type(entry) == list:
                print("entry: " + str(entry[key_list[-1]]) + " = " + str(data))
                entry[key_list[-1]] = data
        except:
            break

    t_file = open(o_name + ".json", "w")
    t_file.write(json.dumps(t_json, indent=2, sort_keys=False))
```

fu.json

```
{
  "someList": [
    "this",
    "is",
    "a",
    "test",
    "fubar",
    1
  ],
  "numbers": 3,
  "AddedInfo": {
    "deeperDict": {
      "level": 3
    },
    "deeperList": [
      4.4,
      123.4
    ]
  }
}
```

bar.json:

```
{
  "someList": [
    "this",
    "test",
    "didnt",
    "work",
    "bufar",
    2
  ],
  "numbers": 3,
  "AddedInfo": {
    "deeperDict": {
      "level": 3
    },
    "deeperList": [
      4.4,
      123.4
    ]
  }
}
```

printed outcome

```
['someList', 0]
data: this
entry: this = this
['someList', 1]
data: is
entry: test = is
['someList', 2]
data: a
entry: didnt = a
['someList', 3]
data: test
entry: work = test
['someList', 4]
data: fubar
entry: bufar = fubar
['someList', 5]
data: 1
entry: 2 = 1
popping list someList
['numbers']
data: 3
['AddedInfo', 'deeperDict', 'level']
data: 3
popping dictionary deeperDict
['AddedInfo', 'deeperList', 0]
data: 4.4
['AddedInfo', 'deeperList', 1]
data: 123.4
popping list deeperList
popping dictionary AddedInfo
```

The result is that there is no change to the data in the designated transfer file. My theory is that the entry variable is referring to a copy of the entry, instead of the place in the file where the actual entry is stored.

*As an added, my current system for getting the keys and values needs work, and any help to improve that is also appreciated.*

Comment: I would start with [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22699047/15452601) and work on the loaded dicts directly, without constructing a general iterator (which is possible, but will only complicate this use-case where it's not clear how to handle e.g. dicts on one side and lists on the other

Comment: Can you provide sample input/output?

Comment: @vnk
['common', 0]
data: pixelmon:mint_seeds
['common', 1]
data: pixelmon:xs_exp_candy
['common', 2]
data: pixelmon:s_exp_candy
['common', 3]
data: pixelmon:absorb_bulb
['common', 4]

Comment: This doesn't seem clear enough. Please add the data in your question if possible.

Comment: @vnk I did some edits to the original code. I figured some of it out, but am now realizing my new code solution doesn't result in any change to the file.

Print statements suggest that it will work. But I believe the variable is referring back to a copy of the data and not the point where the data is in the file in order to make the change.

So I need some way to make that happen.
I will update it with output files tho.

Comment: Actually, it does make a change to the first list, but that's the only thing it transfers info from.